# How to determine optimal state sequence in HMM?

Tags: stochastic-processes, hidden-markov-models

There are several criteria to determine state sequences in HMM. For example, most possible state for each individual observation, most possible pair states, and most possible sequence.

Which one should I use to get meaningful average statistics in each state? For example, mean and variance of daily stock return.

Tried posting this question on quant finance forum but didn't get an answer. Thanks in advance!